# how to solve burning cpu message in Console

Tags: macos, cpu, osx-yosemite

When I run Google Earth or any viewer for Second Life, and it shows 3D imagery, the Console shows a message like the following:

> 26-01-15 19:51:58,000 kernel[0]: process Google Earth[5427] thread 783194 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 63%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 92.019671 seconds, (78.804056 user, 13.215615 system) ledger info: balance: 90001814629 credit: 90004105354 debit: 2290725 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 141633271121

I tried to get around this problem with a command like:

> watch -n 20 renice 20 -p 5427

Although this command runs without any errors, I still keep seeing the same line in the Console.

I currently use OS X 10.10.1 and work around this problem by running the software that would otherwise cause trouble, in Parallels Desktop.

Could someone please point me to a solution, other than reverting back to the previous version of OS X?

Comment: It's just telling you that the thread is using the processor a lot, which could be useful to identify a rogue program which is using the CPU more than it should. However, you *do* want the programs you noted to use the CPU a lot. The easiest solution is to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Andrew, but that is not an option. I've had an app like Firestorm do something like this, resulting in OS X rebooting my computer. That's why I'm so confident that this should not be happening.